# Украшения для баннера ssh. SSH motd

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, printf, login

Возможно моя проблема покажется тривиальной, но я не могу понять по какой причине **cowsay** не может вывести цитаты из **fortune** в баннер при входе по ssh, при том что сама корова рисуется и выводит, описанную в скрипте информацию, но не может подтянуть **fortune** и переменную ***$USER*** ? 
Однако, когда этот-же скрипт просто вызывается из оболочки (в моем случае bash), то такой проблемы не возникает и даже сохраняется форматирование, т.е облако с фразой отображается ровно, ее края образуют ровные столбцы, а не разъезжаются на разные расстояния.
Вот исходный текст моего скрипта

```
#!/bin/sh
# (1)
#!/bin/bash
# (2)
# (1) if this text is update-motd.d's scripts (2) if this text is normal
# bash script
#i3-nagbar -t warning -m 'Проверка вызова нагбара через скрипт' -b 'Закрыть' 
curHour=$(date "+%H")
if [ $curHour -lt 12 -a $curHour -ge 0 ]; then curTime="Доброе утро"
elif [ $curHour -lt 17 -a $curHour -ge 12 ]; then curTime="Добрый день"
else curTime="Добрый вечер"
fi

clever=`/usr/games/fortune`

#System uptime
uptime=`cat /proc/uptime | cut -f1 -d.`
Days=$((uptime/60/60/24))
Hours=$((uptime/60/60%24))
Mins=$((uptime/60%60))
Mem1=`free -t -m | grep "buffers/cache" | awk '{print $3" MB";}'`
Mem2=`free -t -m | grep "Mem" | awk '{print $2" MB";}'`
Procs=`ps aux | wc -l`
IP=`hostname --all-ip-addresses`

if [ $curHour -lt 12 -a $curHour -ge 0 ]; then echo $curTime $USER\
" с момента запуска прошло $Days дней $Hours часов $Mins минут(ы)" | cowsay -b
elif [ $curHour -lt 17 -a $curHour -ge 12 ]; then printf "$curTime $USER\n  
 с момента запуска прошло $Days дней $Hours час(ов) $Mins минут(ы)\n  $Procs процессов запущено\n
 Адресс хоста: $IP\n  $clever"| cowsay
else echo $curTime $USER | cowsay -d
fi

echo ля-ля-ля
echo $Mem1
echo $Mem2
```

Примечание.

Пакеты cowsay и fortune (fortunes-rus) установлены соответственно.

Везде в предложениях вида :

> if [ ... ]; then ...

используется функция **printf**.

Данный скрипт запускается в качестве баннера из директории /etc/update-motd.d/{название-скрипта}

Дистрибутив raspbian-buster

Comment: и куда вы помещаете ваш скрипт?

Comment: В /etc/update-motd.d/{filename}, с правами на исполнение для суперпользователя,

Comment: это существенная информация. потому что содержимое сообщения в разных версиях разных дистрибутивов формируется из очень разных источников. стоит внести её в вопрос. // ну а по поводу `/usr/games/fortune` — указанный вами скрипт выполняется от имени пользователя root, соответственно, надо указать полный путь (каталог `/usr/games`, естественно, отсутствует в переменной PATH у этого пользователя).

Comment: На момент написания комментария отсутствует правка в переменной clever=/usr/games/fortune, текущего скрипта, но это к сожалению не решило проблему, а export PATH=/usr/local/sbin: ... ... :/usr/local/games:/usr/games у рута, привел к тому что стало возможно вызывать fortune и ее производные

Comment: Но в баннер фортунки по прежнему не выводятся и осталась проблема с выводом в баннер $USER, она ведь переменная окружения ?

Comment: во-первых, выполняется скрипт от имени пользователя root, потому, даже если бы переменная и была установлена, то её значение ("root") вам вряд ли бы пригодилось. во-вторых, выполняется скрипт в **не**-login-оболочке, потому значение этой переменной (как и множество иных) просто не определено. можете непосредственно спросить у программы id: `$ id -un`.